# Insert Data into SQL if doesn't exist before using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json, insert

Hello I am trying to insert new client data into my sql table based on if customers_id exists or not.
If the customer_id exists, it should just ignore the client data.
I tried with primary keys, INSERT IGNORE and even with replace. But somehow its not working or just duplicating the existing data.
Could you please help to insert this data from JSON array to SQL based on if customers_id already exists or not.

**This is my Base Code, Of-course this duplicates data and just inserts new data.**

```
 $datas = json_decode($jsondata, true);

 foreach ($datas as $data)
 {
    $customers_id = $data['customers_id'];
    $last_name = $data['last_name'];
    $first_name = $data['first_name'];
    $email = $data['email'];
    $phone = $data['phone'];
    $vat = $data['vat'];
    $country = $data['country'];
    $date_of_birth = $data['date_of_birth'];
    $customers_code = $data['customers_code'];
    $customers_ref_ext = $data['customers_ref_ext'];


 $sql = "INSERT INTO clients(customers_id, last_name, first_name, email, phone, vat, country, date_of_birth,customers_code,customers_ref_ext)
    VALUES('$customers_id', '$last_name', '$first_name', '$email', '$phone', '$vat', '$country', '$date_of_birth', '$customers_code', '$customers_ref_ext')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
  echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
  echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

 }
```

Comment: Your question is difficult to understand. For instance you say: "... based on if customers_id exists or not.", twice, but you don't say what should happen. Insert when it doesn't exist, or when it does exist? It's unclear what you mean by: "I tried with primary keys and even with replace.", should we guess?

Comment: It should ignore and not do anything if it exists already @KIKOSoftware

Comment: OK, you want to do a conditional insert: "Insert only new customers.". Then you need to check if a customer exists before you insert the data. You can do this by checking what `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM clients WHERE customers_id = ?` returns.

Comment: Another way is to use [IGNORE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html)  ("If you use the IGNORE modifier, ignorable errors that occur while executing the INSERT statement are ignored. For example, without IGNORE, a row that duplicates an existing UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY value in the table causes a duplicate-key error and the statement is aborted. With IGNORE, the row is discarded and no error occurs. Ignored errors generate warnings instead.")

Comment: Yes, Luuk is right. But I think you tried to say that didn't work for you. It could. One last thing, before you take this code to production, you might want to read this: [SQL Injection](https://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).

Answer (score 1):

just execute a select query, if it returning record then it means that the record you trying to insert is already exist in table.
$datas = json_decode($jsondata, true);

```
 foreach ($datas as $data)
 {
    $customers_id = $data['customers_id'];
    $last_name = $data['last_name'];
    $first_name = $data['first_name'];
    $email = $data['email'];
    $phone = $data['phone'];
    $vat = $data['vat'];
    $country = $data['country'];
    $date_of_birth = $data['date_of_birth'];
    $customers_code = $data['customers_code'];
    $customers_ref_ext = $data['customers_ref_ext'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM clients where customers_id = ".$customers_id;
    $result = $conn->query($query);

   if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) 
    {
      $sql = "INSERT INTO clients(customers_id, last_name, first_name, email, phone, vat, country, date_of_birth,customers_code,customers_ref_ext) VALUES('$customers_id', '$last_name', '$first_name', '$email', '$phone', '$vat', '$country', '$date_of_birth', '$customers_code', '$customers_ref_ext')";

        if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
            echo "New record created successfully";
        } else {
           echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
        }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Hello, I tried this method. but somehow it ends up duplicating the data

Comment: what you placed in this if condition "if(...)"

Comment: if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0)   update this line

Comment: ($result->num_rows > 0)   I placed this.  But also it should be the opposite to  (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0)  right ?

Comment: yes, check my answer, I have updated it

Comment: its not really working. $result variable is empty. when i execute it.   $query = "SELECT * FROM clients where customers_id = ".$customers_id;    from here, i think there is a problem, probably because we are not using a post or a request method.

Comment: `mysql_num_rows()` hasn't existed for years...

Comment: okay, then you may try similar something else.